# Why am I suddenly getting "Error running hotrestart" when trying to deploy a Xamarin app to a local iPhone?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Out of the blue VS2019 16.8.3 is preventing me from deploying an app to my local iPhone. The error I get is

"Error running hotrestart: 'An unexpected error occurred and the process has been terminated'. Command: 'sign -i="C:\Users\grvin\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Bundles\16.8.000.260\37019337\QRCodeScan.iOS.app" -p="C:\Users\grvin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles\fd76a319-40d6-4add-858b-6511d70b9e55.mobileprovision" -c="C:\Users\grvin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates\1D33FB60B07703E0.p12" -pk="CFBundleIdentifier" -pv="net.companyname.QRCodeScan" -w="bb292e36-0526-477b-9cbf-c285203baefe"'"

When it happened a few weeks ago I resolved it by installing an update that was waiting. However this time there is no update waiting. I think I've tried everything - rebooting, cleaning, building, creating a new app...
I have a suspicion it is something to do with automatic versus manual provisioning. I'm sure it started around the time I used manual provisioning for the first time to deploy an app. Changed back to automatic for local deployment, and now this.

I've logged this with Microsoft via the VS feedback form, but they don't seem to be in a rush to get back to me. All on holidays maybe.
Hopefully someone on this forum can give me some things to try?

Comment: Hi, do you have logined the Apple account for iTunes? You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#initial-setup) to check whether all the steps be finished.

Comment: Yes, done all that. I've been developing successfully with Xamarin for nearly a year now, and have been deploying directly to an iPhone all this time. This error just came out of the blue at me and it has me stuck. The same app deploys perfectly to an iPhone from a different PC.

Comment: Okey, whether this PC can see the iPhone device in the list? If so, the error occurs when you click the **run** button?

Comment: From shared error information, it should be the provisioning file. You could check it 
whether they are the same file with another PC before running it.

Comment: Yes, my PC can see the iPhone device. The error occurs when building, and it occurs when running. Sorry, I don't understand your second response. The files aren't identical across PCs, should they be? What should I be looking for? On my main PC the .mobileprovision files are generally the same compared to when the deployment was working.

Comment: Okey, if they are the same app, they need to use the same bundle ID and the provisioning file also should the same. Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/

Comment: Yes it's the same bundle ID, I copied the source files directly from one PC to the other. I'm using automatic provisioning on both. Provisioning files cannot be easily compared as they are not text files, but I can see the 'DeveloperCertificates' data is different. I don't know if that matters. However even if you say they should be the same, that doesn't help me overcome this problem. If they are different, then VS has caused this, how do I rectify it?
(thanks for the assistance, btw, it's very frustrating not being able to test my app now when i could before)

Comment: You could check whether [the selected Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUcK.png) is the same.

Comment: Yes the teams are the same.

Comment: Oh, have no idea about this now. If you have another PC for testing, you could have a check whether occurs this error.